# How to receive data sent by client through Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

So I want to find out how to receive data that the client has sent. I am currently using this code for my connections:

```
    public void listen()
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
        server.Start();

        while (true)
        {

            Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();


            connected++;

            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

How would I go about receiving ASCII data that has been converted to bytes, then reconverting those bytes to ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a thread in which you will read the data (or you could use the Asynchronous sockets )  from the connection stream.
I have implemented one example of tcp library :
https://github.com/alekstheod/Promasi-V2/tree/master/org.promasi.network/src/org/promasi/network/tcp
check the tcp client and server classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TcpClient instead of Socket while receiving the data using

```
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Code available in MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You really should do research / reading on Sockets/Clients interaction in .NET. The code needed to pull of a simple server/client program is more than any single post on here will tell you.

Comment: I have a simple client/server connection. The client sends data and receives data from the server, but the server doesn't recieve data (which is what I'm trying to learn). Please don't answer just to say that, atleast put it as a comment under OP.

Comment: I put it as an answer because - as my post states - no one can fully get you from where you are to where you need to be using an Answer post on SO. Again, there are NUMEROUS guides/tutorials on the Internet and Google is your friend. You can take the title of your post, take an hour to read a few guides, and get infinitely more information than asking questions on SO will provide for what you need here.